# NSMutableArray randomly releasing objects

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, release

With my app the user can record a drive using LocationManager while on the road for different calculation purposes. These calculations are done in the Class `Calculator`. This usually works fine except for sometimes when apparently the NSMutableArrays `energyArray` and `energyOnlyDriveArray` looses all if its stored values which are then written as nil int Core Data.

Here is the code:

### DriveView Loads

DriveView.h

```
@interface DriveView : UIScrollView <ADBannerViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,CalculatorDelegate>
{
        Calculator *calculator;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) Calculator *calculator;
```

DriveView.m

```
@implementation DriveView

@synthesize calculator = _calculator;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _calculator = [[Calculator alloc]init];
        _calculator.delegate = self;
    } 
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [_calculator locationManagerDidUpdateLocations:locations];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [_calculator locationManagerDidFailWithError:error];
}
```

### User starts recording

DriveView tells the location manager to start updating locations and calls `initData` and `initCarData` when the user starts to record a drive.

### Calculator.h

```
@interface Calculator : NSObject {
@private
NSMutableArray *energyArray;
NSMutableArray *energyOnlyDriveArray;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <CalculatorDelegate> delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *alt_filtered;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *energyArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *energyOnlyDriveArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *powerVectorDict;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *carSpecificData;

- (void)initData;
- (void)initCarData;

...
```

### Calculator.m

```
@implementation Calculator

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize energyArray = _energyArray;
@synthesize energyOnlyDriveArray = _energyOnlyDriveArray;

- (id)init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        _queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initData
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [kDelegate managedObjectContext];
}

- (void)initCarData
{
    _energyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //stores the energy values
    _energyOnlyDriveArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //stores the energy values
    _carSpecificData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _alt_filtered = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [[[Cars manager]carsList] count]; i++) {
        [_energyArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
        [_energyOnlyDriveArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
        [_carSpecificData addObject:[NSDictionary new]];
    }

    ....
}

- (void)locationManagerDidUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    if ((newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0) && (newLocation.verticalAccuracy > 0) && (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 100) && (newLocation.verticalAccuracy < 100)) 
    {
        --> Some code and then `launchAlgorithm:`
    }
}

- (void)launchAlgorithm:(Drive*)drive 
{

    UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
// Request permission to run in the background. Provide an // expiration handler in case the task runs long.

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{

        @autoreleasepool {

            for (int i = 0; i < [[[Cars manager]carsList] count]; i++) {
                [self processAlgorithmResults:[Algorithm that calculation and returns NSDictionary]];
            }

            if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
                    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                });
            }

        }

    });

- (void)processAlgorithmResults:(NSMutableDictionary *)driverProfile
{
    // write energy into array
    float energyValue = [[_energyArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue] + [[driverProfile objectForKey:@"EVerbrauch"] floatValue];
    [_energyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:energyValue]];

    float energyOnlyDriveValue = [[_energyOnlyDriveArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue] + [[driverProfile objectForKey:@"EVerbrauchOnlyDrive"] floatValue];
    [_energyOnlyDriveArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:energyOnlyDriveValue]];

    // set power value
    NSMutableArray *powerValueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_powerVectorDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]]];
    [powerValueArray addObject:[[driverProfile objectForKey:@"P"]valueForKey:@"Pel_drive"]];
    [_powerVectorDict setObject:powerValueArray forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
}

AFTER THE DRIVE IS DONE EVERYTHING IS SAVED LIKE THIS:

- (void)saveHistory
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [[[Cars manager]carsList] count]; i++) {

        // power array of the car
        NSMutableArray *powerArray = [_powerVectorDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

        History *history = (History *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        history.driveID = [[Settings manager]lastDriveID];
        history.distance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_totalDistance];
        history.vMax = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_maxSpeed];
        history.driveDate = firstTime;
        history.sentToServer = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        history.vMean = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_avgSpeed];
        history.energy = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[_energyArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]];
        history.energy_onlyDrive = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[_energyOnlyDriveArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]];
        history.car = [[[[Cars manager]carsList] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        history.carID =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        history.area = [[[[Cars manager]carsList] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"area"];
        history.cw = [[[[Cars manager]carsList] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cw"];
        history.weight = [[[[Cars manager]carsList] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"weight"];
        history.driveDuration = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[lastTime timeIntervalSinceDate:firstTime]];
        history.temperature = [[Settings manager]localTemperature];
        history.temperatureSystem = [[Settings manager]temperatureSystem];
        history.precision = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(((float)_totalSignals-(float)_badSignals))/(float)_totalSignals];
        history.includeInProfile = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        history.maxPower = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[powerArray objectAtIndex:index]floatValue]];
        history.lastSentChunk = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    }


    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@",error.description);
            NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I retrieve the data the values for history.energy and history.energy_onlyDrive return nil value.

The app can also run in the background and will do all the calculations there as well.
I hope somebody can help me out here. I really cant see why the arrays are being cleared which seems kind of random because sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesnt. I is also not relevant how long the calculations go. I have it happen when doing a 3 minute drive as well as a 3 hour drive.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't say the array is losing its values. I believe it is more likely a parsing/conversion/storing error. Do you have access to a "corrupted" database ? How do know `history.energy` is nil, how is it initialized ?

Comment: I just noticed something. Could this be because of the strong reference of the calculator delegate: `@property (strong, nonatomic) id <CalculatorDelegate> delegate;`?

Comment: Well, i don't really know, but the delegate property should indeed be weak, otherwise it won't be released.